# localStorage set to NULL on window object (qtwebkit 2.3.5)

Tags: local-storage, qtwebkit

So, the company that I work for is developing a set top box that uses Qtwebkit 2.3.5 as its frontend solution.

I need to try and make a third party VOD work with the system, but I'm having a problem right in the first step.

The VOD platform (I do not have access to its source code) uses localStorage to keep a few parameters, and apparently Qtwebkit 2.3.5 does not implement it.

My first thought was using a localStorage Polyfill, but after trying a few and going nowhere I started investigating.

The localStorage property inside the window global object is set to null by default, and the system is not letting me change it.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
window.testStorage = "TEST_st";
console.log(window.localStorage);
console.log(window.localStorage = "TEST");
console.log(window.localStorage);
console.log(window.testStorage);
```

Looking at the console I'm getting this logs:

*null
TEST
null
TEST_st*

So, I can add properties to the window object, shown by the testStorage, but I'm not able to change the localStorage, and I need to be able to.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

And, how can I fix it? Would I be able to modify the localStorage property?

Even mapping it to sessionStorage (this one is implemented) would help me at this point.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to answer my own question and maybe help someone.

The window.localStorage functionality is implemented on QtWebkit 2.3.5, but disabled by default.

You have to call:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->enablePersistentStorage();
```

before creating QWebPage or QWebView instance.

Recompile and reboot.

Everything worked fine after that.